# Snowflake stored procedure permission question

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am struggling to grant execute permission on a simple stored procedure

I create the following procedure using the ROLE SYSADMIN

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PUBLIC.SOME_PROC()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS 
$$
  return "Hello";
$$
;
```

I test it by calling it

```
CALL PUBLIC.SOME_PROC();
```

I grant execution as below

```
GRANT USAGE ON PROCEDURE PUBLIC.SOME_PROC() TO ROLE UAT_OPERATIONS;
```

I switch role

```
USE ROLE UAT_OPERATIONS;
```

I try to call it again

```
CALL PUBLIC.SOME_PROC();
```

And I get the following error

> SQL Error [2141] [42601]: SQL compilation error: Unknown user-defined
> function PUBLIC.SOME_PROC

What am I missing???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the same error, I had to make sure to also grant privileges `USAGE ON DATABASE` and `USAGE ON SCHEMA` to the role — otherwise you'll get the `Unknown` error when working within that role.

```sql
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE db TO ROLE UAT_OPERATIONS;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA db.public TO ROLE UAT_OPERATIONS;
GRANT USAGE ON PROCEDURE db.PUBLIC.SOME_PROC() TO ROLE UAT_OPERATIONS;
```

Comment: Oh interesting... I simply assumed public was... public!
I'll try that

Thanks

Comment: Works on me too. Thanks :D